# How to setup a git contrib script with zplug?

Tags: zsh

I want to add auto-installation of diff-highlight thanks to zsh [zplug](https://github.com/zplug/zplug):

```
zplug "git/git", as:command, use:"contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight" \
  hook-build:"cd contrib/diff-highlight && make", \
  depth:1
```

The build hook works and create the binary if I try it manually, but nothing is done nore linked with `zplug install`.

I have this relevant error line:

```
{"pid":27363,"shlvl":1,"level":"INFO","dir":"/home/sullivan/dotfiles","message":"git/git: no matches found, rename_hash is empty","trace":["__zplug::log::write::info:2","__zplug::sources::github::load_command:70","(eval):1","__zplug::core::sources::use_handler:13","__zplug::core::cache::commands:13","__load__:55","__zplug::core::core::run_interfaces:14","zplug:12","/home/sullivan/.zshrc:16","zsh:80"],"date":"2019-02-19T16:16:23+0100"}
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug? If it's a bug, I'll open an issue on the zplug repository.

Thanks